# Javascript string match() method returning error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of null"

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

- Below is my code to match phonenumber string with Regex and return 
  matched string format from the phoneNumber.It takes phoneNumber in
  "+12-787878" format and after regex match returns "+12".
- This code works fine on chrome ,firefox but only on one developer
  machine it is returning error like "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read
  property 'toString' of null" .

> Check out below code.
>   var countryDialCode = phone ?phone.match(CONSTANTS.EXTRACT_DIAL_NUMBER, '').toString(): '';

```
 CONSTANTS.EXTRACT_DIAL_NUMBER = '/^[+]\d+/g';
 phone = "+91-7778889078";
 expected output = "+91";

getDialCodes: function() {
    var phone = SessionStore.getLoggedInUserDialCode();
    if(phone && _.isEmpty(this.refs.contactComponent.refs.cellNumber.refs.input.value)) {

        // Below is the code to extract numbers followed by + sign from the given phonenumber string. 
        var countryDialCode = phone ? phone.match(CONSTANTS.EXTRACT_DIAL_NUMBER, '').toString(): '';

        this.refs.contactComponent.refs.cellNumber.refs.input.value = countryDialCode;
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no matches.

Comment: you should store the result of phone.match(CONSTANTS.EXTRACT_DIAL_NUMBER, '') and check if its not null

Comment: @furrie Yes, I have checked it on my local and on my dev and prod environment its working fine and giving proper matches .Bt one of the developers pc it is returning error , He is using  chromes Version 49.0.2623.110 (64-bit).
is it browser version issue ?

Comment: could be, each browser has its own javascript engine and the can be changed between version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

match method return `null` when string is not matched so you can not call `toString()` on null dataType. You can fix this error as below.

```
$res=phone.match(CONSTANTS.EXTRACT_DIAL_NUMBER, '');
var countryDialCode = phone ? ($res==null? '': $res.toString() ): '';
```

Comment: Hi , Thanks for your valuable answer. Actually this issue was because of data inconsistency . But because of the null check which you have added, error is avoided.

Comment: Change $res.toString to $res.toString().  (y)

Comment: @Kalashir, thanks for your attention... basically where are you from?

Answer (score 1):

.match need regexp and return array as output, so better pass regExp to match method

```
CONSTANTS.EXTRACT_DIAL_NUMBER = /^[+]\d+/g;
phone = "+91-7778889078";
expected output = "+91";

getDialCodes: function() {
    var phone = SessionStore.getLoggedInUserDialCode();
    if(phone && _.isEmpty(this.refs.contactComponent.refs.cellNumber.refs.input.value)) {

        // Below is the code to extract numbers followed by + sign from the given phonenumber string. 

        var countryDialCode = phone ? phone.match(CONSTANTS.EXTRACT_DIAL_NUMBER): [''];
        countryDialCode = countryDialCode[0];
        this.refs.contactComponent.refs.cellNumber.refs.input.value = countryDialCode;
    }
}
```

Give it try if this works or not ?